# Yii2, how to run a command from another command?

Tags: yii2

I would like to make a shortcut to a long command.

The command I have is:
`./yii gii/giiant-crud --modelClass="app\models\Job" --controllerClass="app\modules\admin\controllers\JobController" --searchModelClass="app\models\search\Job" --template="admin"`

The command I want is:
`./yii gii-q/crud job`

I created a command controller, but I'm not sure how to run another command controller from here:

```
<?php namespace app\commands;

use yii\console\Controller;
use yii\helpers\Inflector;

class GiiQController extends Controller
{
    public function actionCrud($table)
    {
        $model = Inflector::classify($table);
        $command = 'gii/giiant-crud --modelClass="app\\models\\' . $model . '" --controllerClass="app\\modules\\admin\\controllers\\' . $model . 'Controller" --searchModelClass="app\\models\\search\\' . $model . '" --template="admin"';
        // how to run command?
    }
}
```

I would prefer to run the yiic-command in the same thread (not by calling `exec`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 - Call a Yii console command from within another console command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420124/yii2-call-a-yii-console-command-from-within-another-console-command)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run an action from within an app with `\Yii::$app->runAction('controller/action', $params);`

Not sure if it's documented, here's its source code https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Controller.php#L118 and the discussion https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1764

In your case it would be:

```
<?php namespace app\commands;

use yii\console\Controller;
use yii\helpers\Inflector;

class GiiQController extends Controller
{
    public function actionCrud($table)
    {
        $model = Inflector::classify($table);
        \Yii::$app->runAction('gii/giiant-crud', [
            "modelClass" => $model,
            "controllerClass" => "app\\modules\\admin\\controllers\\" . $model . "Controller",
            "searchModelClass" => "app\\models\\search\\" . $model,
            "template" => "admin"
        ]);
    }
}
```