# Yii2 - Call a Yii console command from within another console command?

Tags: php, shell, yii2

I have created two different Yii2 console commands/controllers.

Example to call them is

```
# yii user/create-account
```

and

```
# yii webserver/update-config
```

After user/create-account has run I want to call webserver/update-config  - is it possible doing this from within Yii by code? Or do I have to use exec()/system() to externally call the second yii php script (I would prefer not to).

Any help/insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Refer this maybe helpfull :  https://github.com/vova07/yii2-console-runner-extension

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some consideration the way I chose to call one controller from within another was by using the runAction method of the controller (which is also the recommended way by the Yii developers).

Example for a console application:

```
\Yii::$app->runAction('webserver/update-config');
```

It is also possible to hand over params by using an array in as second parameter.

An example for simple parameters:

```
\Yii::$app->runAction('webserver/update-config', ['oneValue', 'anotherValue'];
```

Here an example for named parameters:

```
\Yii::$app->runAction('webserver/update-config', [
    'servertype' => 'oneSetting', 
    'serverdir'  => 'anotherSettingValue'
]);
```

Please note that this makes the called controller a part of the calling code. So if the called controller fails for some reason the whole program fails.
Good error handling is a must. In the called controller you can set the error code to give back by using **return**.

Example:

Calling line of code:

```
$iExitCode = \Yii::$app->runAction('webserver/update-config', ['oneValue', 'anotherValue'];
```

Called controller:

```
<?php
namespace app\commands;

use yii\console\Controller;

/**
* Webserver related functions
*/
class WebserverController extends Controller {
    public function actionUpdateConfig($oneValue, $anotherValue) {
        // Code that does something
        if ($success) return 0;
        else          return 1;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling one action from another (even inside one controller) is not very good practice and clear. I suggest another approach.

Move updating webserver config logic outside of a `Webserver` controller, for example place it in some component / helper.

Then you can call this method from anywhere in particular in both user controller and webserver controller.

Example. In `Webserver` component:

```
public static function updateConfig()
{
    ...
}
```

In `User` controller:

```
public function actionCreateAccount()
{
    ...
    Webserver::updateConfig();
}
```

In `Webserver` controller:

```
public function actionUpdateConfig()
{
    Webserver::updateConfig();
}
```

I think this is more reusable and clear.

Comment: While I think a custom helper is one way to do this I am not sure if this is the right design decision - since it would be a helper which has functions that depends on certain models. I always had the feeling the helpers should be self-contained/independant.

Comment: It can be a component and depend on some classes, models, etc.

Comment: Calling one action from another is way worse for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Variant 1**

You can run one action of controller from another action. For example,

```
public function actionCreateAccount() {
    // something
}

public function actionUpdateConfig() {
    // something
}

public function actionComplex() {
    $this->actionCreateAccount();
    $this->actionUpdateConfig();
}
```

Or

```
public function actionCreateAccount() {
    // something
    $this->actionUpdateConfig();
}

public function actionUpdateConfig() {
    // something
}
```

**Variant 2**

If you neet to call action of another controller, you can use [run()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#run()-detail) method of console controller:

For example, action in WebmasterController:

```
public function actionUpdateConfig($param1, $param2)
{
    echo $param1 . '/' . $param2 . PHP_EOL;
}
```

action in UserController:

```
public function actionCreateAccount()
{
    echo 'test: ';
    $this->run('webmaster/update-config', ['do', 'it']);
}
```

Comment: He wants to call action of another controller.

Comment: Then it is good variant to use run() method of console controller. For example, action in WebmasterController:

`
 public function actionUpdateConfig($param1, $param2)
 {
  echo $param1 . '/' . $param2 . PHP_EOL;
 }
`

action in UserController:

`
 public function actionCreateAccount()
 {
  echo 'test: ';
  $this->run('webmaster/update-config', ['do', 'it']);
 }
`